# How to quit an automatically run script on startup in Python Kivy?

Tags: boot, python-3, gui, lxterminal, desktop

I run a script at startup with the command line `@lxterminal -e /home/pi/Desktop/Python3/myApp.sh` in the file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` which I created with `nano`, not with `sudo nano` as suggested in many posts.

The `myApp.sh` runs the script in a virtual environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Python3
sleep 2
source /home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/bin/activate
sleep 2
python /home/pi/Desktop/Python3/myApp.py
#bash   # to keep the terminal window open
```

I have the following setup:

Raspbian

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Python

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Kivy

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-52d12eb, 20200108
```

**ISSUE**
After exiting myApp.py or killing it with ALT+F4, I end up with a black screen with the options (mouse right click) of the terminal, restart, apps etc.
[image: black screen with selection]

If I try to startx from the terminal I get the error:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ startx

```
xauth: (stdin):2:  unknown command "4ff84eb64464df73460f05fee323c32b"
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-99-generic armv8l Raspbian
Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:65:15:C9 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles usbhid.mousepoll=0
Build Date: 07 July 2020  09:38:51PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+rpt2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Aug 19 11:01:34 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to end up with the original startx desktop GUI?

Comment: You refer to the fact that you "end up with a black screen with the options (mouse right click) of the terminal" -- presumably you mean a GUI terminal since the console doesn't have a mouse menu.  Where are you then trying to start X from?  There?  In any case **it's still running.**  You have to kill it, or the session belonging to the pi user.  The latter may be preferable as the GUI login (`lightdm`) should then be available.  If not, kill the service (`sudo systemctl stop lightdm`), the X server (look for processes named `Xorg`), then try `sudo systemctl start lightdm` or `startx`.

Comment: I think your App.py is the problem. It probably uses Kivy to initalize a FullScreen application (just guessed) and if you leave the program you forget to free resources, or switch back to the windows mode. Like goldilocks I think the X-Server / Wayland is still running and the LXDE Desktopmanager runs also but you are locked in the fullscreen mode and the lx terminal is active. Perhaps  you can leave the fullscreen mode by pressing <F11>. I use this Key to change the Mode of my Firefox from full screen to windows mode and vice versa. ;-)

Comment: Yes @goldilocks, I mean the mean a GUI terminal and also as Peter Paul Kieter commented, Kivy does run a fullscreen app.

Comment: So you are trying to use `startx` in a GUI terminal?  >_<

Comment: @goldilocks, I am trying to end up on the original RPi desktop after exiting my Kivy/Python app.

Comment: Right.  I presume what Peter PK suggested didn't work either then....

Comment: Right @goldilocks, the <F11> does not work.

Comment: And the "restart" and "exit" menu options don't work either... Try `ctrl-alt-F[N]`, where N is from 1 to 6.  This switches between the six (non-GUI) consoles that have a login prompt running on them (actually one of them will have the X server server running on it, probably the first one).  They look the same except for a `tty` number. From one of those  you can log in, kill X and start it again (that's the command line where `startx` will work -- it won't work inside a GUI terminal). If that doesn't do anything, then you are out of options beyond logging in remotely or via UART.